# Created a 2nd Nginx server using the same public IP using freenom domain and cloudflare nameserver but "The site can't be reached"

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns, cloudflare, certbot

Hello fellow developers,

I was following this guide (https://medium.com/@federicodeicas/how-to-setup-your-server-with-freenom-tk-82c7302bcce4) to setup/simulate an Nginx server running on Ubuntu in VirtualBox with bridge enabled. My first attempt was a success.

However, when I try to redo the same steps for a 2nd domain on a second ubuntu server in a different virtualbox environment with the same public IP address (both running on the same machine), I get a "This site can’t be reached" error, despite successfully obtain the new SSL certificate for the 2nd domain

What could possibly be the problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Only one server can receive requests for a given IP/Port without load balancers or proxies. You cannot map two different virtual machines to the same IP address and port combination.

Comment: thanks for the response, a few more questions
1. how to implement load balancer in this case?
2. assuming the first virtual machine is turned off, but the 2nd virtual machine is on, why is it still not able access the 2nd domain which is hosted on the 2nd VM?

Comment: Create a new post for each question that you have.